# running gradle jettyRun error

Tags: gradle, dependencies, spring-boot

I am trying to run my spring Boot Application using gradle jettyRun but when gradle is compilingJava these errors appear:

> alberto@alberto-desktop:~/Credito/PalmasServer$ gradle jettyRun
>   :compileJava
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>    What went wrong:
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
>   Could not find org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:.
>     Required by:
>         :PalmasServer:unspecified
>   Could not find org.hsqldb:hsqldb:.
>     Required by:
>         :PalmasServer:unspecified
>   Could not find com.h2database:h2:.
>     Required by:
>         :PalmasServer:unspecified
>   Could not find nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:.
>     Required by:
>         :PalmasServer:unspecified
>   Could not find org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3:.
>     Required by:
>         :PalmasServer:unspecified
>   Could not find org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:.
>     Required by:
>         :PalmasServer:unspecified
>   Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   BUILD FAILED

Total time: 35.664 secs

And this is my build.gradle File:

> ```
>   buildscript {
>     ext {
>         springBootVersion = '1.1.9.RELEASE'
>     }
>     repositories {
>         maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
>         mavenLocal()
>     }
>     dependencies {
>         classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.1.9.RELEASE")
>     }
> }
> apply plugin: 'java'
> apply plugin: 'eclipse'
> apply plugin: 'idea'
> apply plugin: 'war'
> apply plugin: 'jetty'
> apply plugin: 'application'
> sourceCompatibility = 1.7
> targetCompatibility = 1.7
> war {
>    version =  '0.1.0'
> }
> repositories {
>     mavenCentral()
>     maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
>     maven { url "http://maven.springframework.org/milestone" }
>     flatDir {
>         dirs 'lib'
>     }
> }
> dependencies {
>     compile "xerces:xercesImpl:2.9.0"
>     compile "net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.12"
>     compile "nekohtml:nekodtd:0.1.11"   
>     compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}")
>     compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:${springBootVersion}")
>     compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}")
>     compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:${springBootVersion}")
>     compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}")
>     compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}")
>     compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc")
>     compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:1.0.2.RELEASE")
>     compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.0.0.RC2")
>     compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2-javaconfig:1.0.0.M1")
>     compile("org.hsqldb:hsqldb")
>     compile("com.h2database:h2")
>     compile("com.google.guava:guava:17.0")
>     compile("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2")
>     compile("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.4")
>     compile("com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.0")
>     compile("commons-io:commons-io:2.4")
>     compile("com.github.davidmarquis:fluent-interface-proxy:1.3.0")
>     compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:1.0.2.RELEASE")
>    compile ("javax.servlet:jstl:1.2")
>    compile ("commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1")
>     testCompile("junit:junit")
>     compile("nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect") 
>     compile("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3")
>      compile("org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4")
>      def poiVersion = "3.10.1"
>     compile "org.apache.poi:poi:${poiVersion}"
>     compile "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:${poiVersion}"
>    compile "org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.1"
> }
> jar {
>     baseName = 'gs-uploading-files'
>     version =  '0.1.0'
> }
> task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
>     gradleVersion = '1.11'
> }
> ```

Why when i am running in Eclipse all is OK????

Any other idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following piece of code:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
```

to `dependencies` block.

Comment: that worked but not all these dependencies are on my local Folder. The rest must be dowloaded. If I run the project in eclipse all works fine. Any idea?

Comment: So what's not working? You can specify local dependencies along with remote (grom maven e.g.).

Comment: So, now gradle is getting the dependencies locally (not all of them are in my local folder) and the rest of them must to be dowloaded. now 6 of these remotes dependencies are not found. But if I run the project in Eclipse all works. Do you know why? I have updated with the new error.

Comment: Is that project accessible online?

Comment: No, what do you need?

Comment: I'd like to reproduce it locally cause I don't get it right now.

Comment: Sorry I was totally wrong! The local dependencies still are not gotten by Gradle with `compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])` . Do you know any other way to include the locals dependencies to gradle? Thank you

Comment: Basically this is how it works. Please provide the project online.